How to understand or define the programming paradigm of Mathematica？
Recently, I have been struggling with the task of writing a Mathematica programming tutorial for my graduate students. My goal is to teach my students how to use Mathematica for complex scientific computing and programming tasks, rather than merely treating it as a "higher-level computer" or a "solver." Below are my considerations regarding the programming paradigms I should adopt for teaching:
1.Functional programming
Using traditional functional programming paradigms, similar to Haskell, Lisp, or PureScript, as teaching content seems ideal for maximizing both development efficiency and computational performance in Mathematica. This is due to the simplicity of the programming model and the ease of parallel computing (since function calls or evaluations tend to be faster in Mathematica). However, the major drawback is that functional programming is often too abstract and may hinder practical application. Additionally, compared to Turing machines, the concepts surrounding $\lambda$ calculus are relatively complex and harder to understand. Mathematica itself is not strictly functional, which could introduce confusion.
2.Procedure oriented programming
Teaching Procedural-Oriented Programming (POP), as exemplified by languages such as C++, Java, and Fortran, could also be an effective approach. This would naturally include object-oriented programming (OOP) or aspect-oriented programming (AOP) techniques. Why do I consider this? Although Mathematica incorporates substantial C++ programming style (of course,using functions, object-oriented classes, structures, and generics), its performance is often subpar (for instance, due to its inherent procedural iteration format). However, I hope that my students should be able to use C++ or C to develop and encapsulate high-performance Mathematica packages (like CMathematica) for addressing more complex problems—ranging beyond scientific computing to areas such as network programming, game development, image processing, and artificial intelligence. This approach would offer significant opportunities for performance optimization, provide clarity in terms of business logic, and improve code readability. The downside, however, is that the code tends to be more verbose, and although Mathematica supports various basic types and generics, it is not a statically-typed language in the strict sense. The "pseudo-type" nature of Mathematica is well-suited for scientific computations and mathematical operations but may pose challenges for general-purpose programming—It seems that a natural barrier has been artificially added.
3.Multiparadigm programming
Programming languages such as Python, R, Java, and JavaScript embody a multiparadigm approach. I favor this programming style due to its flexibility and adaptability. It balances performance requirements without being overly stringent, allowing for a compromise between code readability and simplicity—much like composing an elegant piece of prose. The main disadvantage is that the form's flexibility could lead to an unpredictable and potentially endless spectrum of solutions—so amazing lower and upper limits. The integration of multiple paradigms—such as determining which paradigm should be the "first-class citizen" (types,functions or expressions)—poses significant challenges in unifying and reconciling disparate computational models. Moreover, understanding and applying knowledge from multiple computational models (Turing machines, $\lambda$ calculus, Cellular automata, Symbolic algebra, and Quantum computing) becomes increasingly complex.

I would appreciate any advice you might have on these matters. Thank you.


These are good books on Wolfram language elementary-introduction by Wolfram and   Leonid Shifrin have good book online, but his web site is down. Another good book is David Wagner's Power Programming with Mathematica: The Kernel. see what-mathematica-book-to-buy as for your main question, I think for Mathematica, best to stick to functional programming as it is the most natural fit for how it is designed from the ground up.

Mathematica itself is not strictly functional, which could introduce confusion. see for reference on this topic what-makes-mathematica-a-functional-programming-language  and FunctionalProgramming at Wolfram where it says Functional programming is a highly developed and deeply integrated core feature of the Wolfram Language  So the Wolfram language is functional language according to Wolfram :)

Welcome to this forum. I interpret your questions as asking how to teach a programming course in Mathematica. However, some important information about the structure of your course is missing. For instance, how many hours do you have and what is the background of your students.

You appreciate the flexibility of the multiparadigm approach, but you think it's potentially confusing that Mathematica isn't strictly functional. Sounds like you're rationalizing.

You're struggling with writing a tutorial. You have three programming paradigms that you're considering adopting. Are you struggling to show how Mathematica can be used in conformance with each of those paradigms, or are you struggling to choose which paradigm best fits Mathematica? Is your tutorial focused on teaching best practices for using Mathematica, or is it focused on applying generic best practices to Mathematica programming?

Can you provide a few concrete examples of tutorial content that you need help with so that we can get a feel for what you're actually asking for?

Your title asks how to understand the paradigm of Mathematica. The core paradigm of Mathematica programming is expression rewriting. There's a bunch of additional stuff around that to make it a practical language, but it will be difficult to fully understand Mathematica if you don't understand expression rewriting.

Thank you all for your thoughtful suggestions. I apologize for any confusion caused by my imprecise wording. What I’d like to ask is which programming paradigm would be best suited to my teaching style, with applications spanning areas such as computational science, artificial intelligence, data mining, game programming, and more.

Some related Q&A (see titles to the right under "Linked"): (838), (24988), (109888), (110067), (147679), (163992)
And the comments here: (112920)

In fact, I’ve always believed that Mathematica is a purely functional programming language. As a result, I’ve faithfully followed the teaching content of functional programming languages. However, many of my bright students have been quick to provide countless counterexamples that challenge my view, arguing that MMA isn’t truly functional in the pure sense.

They’ve pointed out many details and principles that contradict my understanding of functional programming, based on my experience with Haskell and Lisp. Even though I’ve insisted, “Look, it has everything a functional language should have—functions, currying, lazy evaluation, recursion, and so on. It may be a little different, but it’s fundamentally functional, much like Lisp. If it looks like an elephant, it must be an elephant,” their critiques have made me reconsider.

A word means whatever a community agrees to mean by that word. When communication spans communities or when community affiliation isn't clear, words are ambiguous. The term "functional programming" invites ambiguity. The disagreement about what it means has less to do with what it means than it has to do with the context of usage and community membership. One definition of "functional programming" might be "it feels a lot like lambda calculus". Another might be "immutability and no side effects". Another might be "functions are first class".

I don't find it particularly interesting to try to come to an ultimate conclusion about whether Mathematica IS a functional language. For any given definition of "functional", one can almost certainly write Mathematica code that exemplifies that definition. For any definition of "functional" one can almost certainly write Java code that exemplifies that definition. For a given definition of "functional" the Mathematica example will very likely be more idiomatic than the Java example. So, I guess in that sense it's reasonable to say that Mathematica is more functional than Java.

To say your understanding of functional programming comes from Haskell and Lisp is very interesting. If both Lisp and Haskell are functional, then that illustrates my point about ambiguity. If your students agree that Lisp is functional, then I think they'd have to admit that Mathematica is functional, for whatever that's worth. I'm not saying that Lisp and Mathematica are equivalent, but I'm having a hard time thinking of a definition of "functional" that would admit Lisp and exclude Mathematica.

@lericr It may sound a bit dull, but our intention is to determine which design patterns are acceptable or well-suited for Mathematica. Different philosophical perspectives can lead to distinct programming principles (the style of writing textbooks and the business logic of software engineering are completely different). Given this, we find it necessary to carefully examine our starting point.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Re "which programming paradigm would be best suited to...": As a teacher (of mathematics, not cs or programming), I would start from what's best for the students and use my teaching style(s) to help the students achieve those goals. I like Mma as a term-rewriting system and feel one cannot have a good understanding of it except as such.
If the learning goals of the course do not build on rewriting systems, then maybe Mathematica is not a good fit.
On the other hand, the evolution of Mathematica as a commercial product has naturally been influenced by serving customers, both current and potential.  This has led it to try to accommodate any programming paradigm any customer might prefer. Beyond accommodating individual styles, the number of high-level functions has grown to support programming in almost any area to which computing may be applied.  Functionality that is supplied by third-party libraries or packages in other languages are built into "Wolfram Language." There are lacuna, of course, that are sometimes filled by external, sometimes commercial, packages. But the breadth of what is supported make it a reason for some to choose it.  Much of the high-performance functions call libraries that are compiled from some other language.  So if the learning goals of the course may be built on parts of this broad functionality (e.g. LLM/ML/NN functions), then Mma may be a good choice. But such a use seems to "[treat] it as a 'higher-level computer'
or a 'solver.'"

Thank you. I will carefully consider your feedback.  What do you think are the practical advantages of the term-rewriting system?

@SophiaThary What I meant was that to understand how Mma works, one should understand it as a rewriting system. Not as functional, not as procedural. Functional programming is possible in Mma, and it's often a good style to use. But when something works or doesn't work, it's sometimes helpful to know what Mma is doing.

As for the practicality, some problems seem easy to think about in terms of input /. rule1 /. rule2.... Almost the same as the functional input // func1 // func2.... Six of one, half a dozen of the other perhaps. Consider that Show[plot2d /. {Graphics -> Graphics3D,  Line -> Tube, {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y, 0.}}, PlotRange -> All] turns a 2d plot into a 3d plot in the xy plane in xyz space. I think of rewriting the parts of the expression.

@SophiaThary More examples: I have 40 answers on this site that use the TransformationFunctions option of Simplify and FullSimplify. Almost all the transformations I've used have the form # /. rule &, which is a way to turn a rewriting rule into a lambda function. The best of both worlds, ha-ha. The option requires a functional approach; the function is constructed from a rewriting point of view. I don't worry about the input as a whole; if it contains parts like "this", then do "that" to them.
